# How to INSERT a select/option from html AND also INSERT a variable from array_rand in a SQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I am using a XAMPP stack. I have successfully retrieved the user's choice of rock, paper, or scissors and inserted it into the table. I have also successfully generated a random "choice from the opponent" by using array_rand but i can't insert this variable/integer into the table ALSO at the same time. I was able at one time to insert the "opponents choice" but never also with the users choice, its always one or the other. And, i figure that i would convert both choices to integers and then use if/else statements to determine the winner of each game but as i've tested this, it doesn't always seem to produce the correct answer. I think there is probably some unnecessary code such as var_dump which i have in there so i can see that I have successfully converted the choices into integers so that i can compare the choices in order to logically determine a winner, for example. Thank you for any help.

```
<html> 

<body>

    <p> Make your move! Choose:</p> 
    <p> Paper, Rock, or Scissors</p> 
        <form action="rps.php" method="post" id="playform">


            <select name="playermove" id="quantity"> 
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Rock</option> 
                <option value="2">Paper</option> 
                <option value="3">Scissors</option> 
            </select> 
        </form>

        <button type="submit" form="playform" value="submit">1, 2, 3....GO!
 </button>
</body> 
</html> 
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$conn    = Connect();
$pmove   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['playermove']);
$omove   = $conn->(['oppmove']);


$query   = "INSERT into rpstwo.tb_rps2 (playermove) VALUES ('" . $pmove . 
"')";

$success = $conn->query($query); 

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
}

$yourvar = intval($pmove);
echo "You chose: " . $yourvar . "<br>";
var_dump($yourvar);
echo "<br>";

    $oppdecision = array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors');
    $oppresult = array_rand($oppdecision, 1);
    echo "Your opponent chose: " . $oppresult . "<br>";
    $oppsmove = $oppdecision[$oppresult];
    echo $oppsmove . "<br>";

    $oppvar = intval($oppresult);

    var_dump($oppvar);


    $sql   = "INSERT into rpstwo.tb_rps2 (oppmove) VALUES ('" . $omove . 
 "')";
    $success = $conn->query($sql); 

     if ($yourvar = 1 & $oppvar = 0) {
        echo '<br>' . "you tie";
    } elseif ($yourvar = 1 & $oppvar = 1) {
        echo '<br>' . "you lose";
    }  elseif ($yourvar = 1 & $oppvar = 2) {
         echo '<br>' . "you win";
    }  else {
        echo '<br>' . "Good game!";
    } 

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please tag appropriately. MySQL and SQL-server are very different in syntax.

Comment: Sorry Sloan Thrasher, i was working on so many different variations that i got mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

The code below fixes your posting to a DB. It does not fix the issues of WIN/LOSE/DRAW possibilities. You should also know that your code posts an integer for playermove and text (rock,paper,scissors) for opponent move. You having two Insert statements will cause 2 separate rows to be created per game.

```
$pmove   = $_POST['playermove'];

$yourvar = intval($pmove);
echo "You chose: " . $yourvar . "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$oppdecision = array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors');
$oppresult = array_rand($oppdecision, 1);
echo "Your opponent chose: " . $oppresult . "<br>";
$oppsmove = $oppdecision[$oppresult];
echo $oppsmove . "<br>";

$oppvar = intval($oppresult);


$sql   = "INSERT into tb_rps2 (oppmove,playermove) VALUES ('$oppresult','$pmove')";
$success = $conn->query($sql); 

 if ($yourvar = 1 & $oppvar = 0) {
    echo '<br>' . "you tie";
} elseif ($yourvar = 1 & $oppvar = 1) {
    echo '<br>' . "you lose";
}  elseif ($yourvar = 1 & $oppvar = 2) {
     echo '<br>' . "you win";
}  else {
    echo '<br>' . "Good game!";
} 

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Updated the answer so the INSERT only posts the integers.

Comment: Yes, this works, Thank you BIlly. So i see that you removed "real_escape_string" out of "$pmove   = $_POST['playermove'];". AND combined two statements into one and removed the database name "rpstwo" and just left the table name "tb_rps2"  in "$sql   = "INSERT into tb_rps2 (oppmove,playermove) VALUES ('$oppresult','$pmove')";". Is there one specific thing that fixed the actual problem and the other changes were just to clean up code? Or were all changes necessary to fix problem? Thank you